# Flutter force refresh page

Tags: flutter, refresh, reload

Is there a way to force page to reload when using on Pressed except using setState is there any other way to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try popping and pushing the same page again

Comment: Why is it so bad to use setState?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => thisPage()));
```